# Title bar buttons in Thunderbird 115 in different order

Tags: ppa, thunderbird

Today I've got the upgrade from Thunderbird 102.15.1 to version 115.2.3, courtesy of the [Mozilla Team PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Emozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=jammy). The window buttons / title bar buttons in TB 115 are in a different order than for every other window. See a screenshot showing Thunderbird's button (top) and Nautilus' buttons (below).

[image]

In Thunderbird, the buttons are in the order `Close` - `Maximize` - `Minimize`, while the default order for every other window is `Close` - `Minimize` - `Maximize`.

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.3. As far as I can tell, the problem isn't called by AddOns, Themes or the like.

This seems like a minor problem, but it turns out to be quite annoying when one app is behaving different from everything else. Is there a way to adjust the order for Thunderbird to match the default order?

Comment: We're witnesses yet another example where a company forces their poor design decisions on unsuspecting users. This contempt for a person's "muscle memory" is most frustrating. Where I once could use Thunderbird with my eyes closed, like you, I'm now forced to look to Google, YouTube, StackExchange, etc for answers about how to make it the way it used to be. The way I was productive. 

Just like Microsoft pooched Windows with Windows 8 and Google flipped us the birdie with GA4, Mozilla are shafting us with their stupid changes. 

Will they ever learn?

Comment: 2 decades of my muscle memory has been assaulted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the new version of Thunderbird, window buttons are provided as client side decorations, i.e., these are drawn by the application itself. If the application then does not follow standards of your desktop environment, the buttons may not match. Apart from editing source code and recompiling Thunderbird yourself, there is little else you can do than to file an issue to the developpers.

To work around, you can disable the client side window buttons by adding classic window decoration. In Thunderbird Settings, General, section "Language & Appearance", uncheck "Hide system window title bar".

Comment: This worked great, TY.